# Is there any ways to run any method or line of code after @AfterSuite in TestNG?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, testng, test-report

**I am having below configuration,**

1. Maven project
2. Execute test case through `testng.xml`
3. External code to write report

Here I have write code to generate reports. It depends on complete all test cases and even after `@AfterSuite` .

> **So is there any way to run that code after completing all test cases or generate test-output folder before complete all the code?**

**Example :**

```
@AfterSuite
public static void tearDown()
{
    try
    {
        driver.quit();
        driver = null;

        //report code, I want this code run after completing aftersuite
        // or generate test-output folder before completing aftersuite
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //code for error
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just add a report generation step in Maven?

Comment: Which reporting tool r u using with Selenium?

Comment: Could you please add the code which you HV written for reporting purpose..

Comment: @ernie Can you please tell the steps in maven ? One small example is enough.

Comment: @BharatMane Yes. I am generating report from this link. http://automationtesting.in/generate-excel-report-in-selenium-using-testng/

Answer (score 1):

Annotations transformers is your answer. You can intercept and change any annotation behaviour.
http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotationtransformers

Comment: Can you please give example code?

Comment: Check some example here in 1.2.4. Example of Configuration annotation transformer:
http://gururajhm.blogspot.fi/p/12-example-of-iannotationtransformer.html

Comment: You also could use [listeners](http://www.swtestacademy.com/how-to-use-testng-listeners/) to intercept Annotation call and do something before or after.